# setDescription in firebase app invite on iOS doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: ios, firebase

Folks,

I am trying to use firebase app invite in my iOS app (swift). I am trying to customize the email body that gets sent out to include details about my app.

I have invite.setDescription("My app description") and invite.setCallToActionText("Download my app") in the invite but that doesn't seem to have any effect. The sent email has correct subject but the body of the email is some default "Install my application" where Install is clickable and the link works correctly. Am I missing something here?

I also use firebase app invite in my android app and I do customize the email message there using android apis setEmailHtmlContent and it works perfectly fine.

Help appreciated,
Abhijit

Comment: experiencing same problem. did you manage to sort it out?

Comment: nope. Still trying to find solution for it.